# Do you have to re-purchase Minecraft Bedrock Edition on different Android phones?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

Do you have to re-purchase Minecraft Bedrock Edition again if you've already bought it on another device?

Like if you bought it on an android phone and you're​ getting a new android phone do you have to re-purchase, or will it just transfer with your Google account?

Answer (score 10):

Purchases are specific to your account, not your device. **No, you do not need to re-purchase Minecraft PE**.

If you switch to another mobile OS like iOS, you will of course need to purchase it again, though.

Answer (score 1):

On the mobile platform, you will need to purchase it again when you switch to a different mobile OS (example Android to iOS).
However, on the Windows 10 version, if you have an Xbox account your progress is synced to, you can download the free trial and sign in with the Xbox account you used on the phone, and it will disable trial mode.